# List invited, co-authored conference presentation on CV as student

Tags: publications, conference, cv, invited-paper

As a student (M.Sc.), my list of publications is as short as my career would suggest. For an invited talk at a conference that my professor gave, parts of my work were presented and I was consequently officially listed as a co-author.

Refining my CV for the application to a PhD position now, do I list this on my CV in the "Publications" section? I've read that this can be interpreted as "blowing up" your CV in some cases, which is really not my intention. But given that people in my career stage normally haven't had a whole lot of opportunities to show their work in public, this might still be of interest.

Thus my question: should I include it or not?

Comment: What's the field? 'Cause in e.g. CS, conference talks are often more important than journal articles, and are regarded as publications. In physics, however, articles are most important, and conference presentations are exactly that: conference presentations. The project that such a talk originated from is more important - hence CV-includable - than the conference, regardless of where you the presenter or not.

Comment: It is physics, optics to be precise - so with a strong link to engineering, which is also the subject of the PhD I am applying to.

Comment: @corey979 Correction: In computer science, conference *presentations* per se are not that important.  However, CS conference **papers** —which are at least as rigorously peer-reviewed as physics journal articles—are more important (at least at this career stage) than CS journal articles, because they have more visibility and more immediate impact.

Answer (score 1):

If you are listed as a co-author, I'd say yes, include it. You could list it in a separate section of your cv below other, more personal work. If you are asked about it, you can describe it as you do here. This is even better if the reason for the invitation was the work itself and not only the stature of the professor.

But it would also be good to get advice from your professor on this.